# How to make all string in an object to uppercase in javascript

Tags: javascript

For example I have an object:

```
{name:"Ken", address:"Sample", location:"Sample"}
```

How do I make the name, address and location in one code using javascript without using like `name.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: You need to iterate over the properties of the object, and then update their values to uppercase. Tagging a duplicate of how to iterate over properties as you already know how to update them to uppercase.

Comment: is it an assignment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a revival function of [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and then check the type and if a string, check if the character is in `a ... z` range, then subtract `32` from the character code to get an upper case letter.

```js
const
    uc = c => c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'
        ? String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt() - 32)
        : c,
    toUpperCase = (key, value) => typeof value === 'string'
        ? Array.from(value, uc).join('')
        : value

var object = { name: "Ken", address: "Sample", location: "Sample" };

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object), toUpperCase));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce()` on the `Object.keys`. This method will not mutate the original object.

```js
let obj = {name:"Ken", address:"Sample", location:"Sample"};
let result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((ac,k) => ({...ac,[k]:k.toUpperCase()}),{})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `for...in` and `toUpperCase` like so:

```js
const data = {
  name: "Ken",
  address: "Sample",
  location: "Sample"
};

let upperCased = {};

for (var key in data) {
  upperCased[key] = data[key].toUpperCase();
}

console.log(upperCased);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use a buildin method like toUpperCase() ?
If you dislike it you can wirtie your own method which check in a str every char, if it's value is in range 97-122 (a - z) then it subtract 32 transposing lowercase ASCII to uppercase ASCII (A - Z).
using buildin method seems more sane.

**Here is a way to iterate trought dict and uppercase any of it's values**

```
    $tmp = {name:"Ken", address:"Sample", location:"Sample"}
    $uppercase_tmp = {name: "", address: "", location: ""}

    $keys = Object.keys($uppercase_tmp);

    for($i = 0; $i < $keys.length; $i++) { 
        /* for each key in uppercase_tmp*/
        $uppercase_tmp[$keys[$i]] = $tmp[$keys[$i]].toUpperCase()
    }
```

---

Hoping it helps.
Hele